# Strange Characters When Writing To Excel File With C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to create an excel document with C#.net. But after I could write some values into the cells properly, last cells have strange characters like which is not related with the content that I readed from a simple txt file:

�����Q%RSIG5oH�g7�j�FnJ�9������RG8��P;���K}r����i�������:�+�J    �F��]dF��Y���Pd���1�C�׽OӘ$D0�..r

Here is my excel creator class:

```
class CreateExcelDoc
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelUygulama;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelProje;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelSayfa;
    object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ExcelRange;



    string s_dosyaadi = "";
    string s_veri = "";

    public CreateExcelDoc()
    {

        ExcelUygulama = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        ExcelProje = ExcelUygulama.Workbooks.Add(Missing);

        ExcelSayfa = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelProje.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        ExcelRange = ExcelSayfa.UsedRange;

        ExcelSayfa = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelUygulama.ActiveSheet;

        ExcelUygulama.Visible = false;

        ExcelUygulama.AlertBeforeOverwriting = false;
    }

    public void HucreyeYaz(int row, int col, string s_veri) // write to a cell
    {

        if (s_veri != "" && row != 0 && col != 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range bolge = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelSayfa.Cells[row, col];
            bolge.Value2 = s_veri; 


        }

    }

    public void Kaydet() // saves the excel document
    {


            ExcelProje.SaveAs(@"C:\excels\dosya.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Missing, Missing, false, Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);

            ExcelProje.Close(true, Missing, Missing);

            ExcelUygulama.Quit();


    }

}
```

Comment: where is s_veri assigned some value ?

Comment: There might be a problem with the actual file that you are reading from. It might have some special characters that might be misinterpreted when written to excel.

Comment: one of lines that causes problem: T 1 .J68 1937 c.233-224

Comment: Which encoding do you use in Excel and the text file?

Comment: ansi and utf8 both of them.

Comment: your workbook default format might be `97/xls` format and your are naming it to `xlsx` format. so, when you are opening it with excel, it is miss interpreted. though this is just a hunch. try changing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault` to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Ms Office libraries, you can create html document by inserting your data and save it as xlsx file. Because, if you depend on the Ms Office libraries you may have to install office on the machine on which you run your application.

You can save an excel file as html and you can modify its contents from your application and save it as xlsx file.